# Inconsistent pose when exporting rigged model to UE4

Tags: rigging, armature, export

I'm having a problem where when I work with my model in Blender its pose is equal on both sides, but when I import to UE4 it gets this weird inconsistency in the left arm that rotates and lifts it in a weird way. Is this common? Is it something wrong I'm doing in blender, or UE4? Is there a quick fix for this? There is one simple idle animation attached to it, if that makes a difference.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have keyframes?

Comment: I've responded to this post twice but was having computer problems, sorry. But yes, I do have keyframes.